Google SSO not working properly on flaks application
I am trying to integrate google SSO login on a flask application but it gives me some error. (The error and code is mentioned in the later part of the question).
I encountered some issues while setting up Google Authentication for the project. Initially, I replaced the GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID with the one I created. While running the application on 127.0.0.1, I noticed the Google SSO button did not appear. After some debugging and some discussion on stack overflow, I discovered that the button does not show up on 127.0.0.1 but does appear when the application runs on localhost. I modified the config file to run the project on localhost:3000, and the Google SSO button finally appeared on the screen with my google_client_id.
However, upon attempting to log in, I received the following error:
GSI_LOGGER
I investigated this error and found that it might be caused by the use of HTTP instead of HTTPS on localhost. According to the official documentation and screenshot below, localhost should be exempt from this rule as I can not run HTTPS server on localhost.
google validation rules
Error is "login_uri is not allowed for the given client ID." Here is the screenshot for my Authorized JavaScript Origin and Authorized JavaScript Redirects:
Authorized JS Origin and Authorized JS Redirects
The Code:
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

<div id="redresp">
{% if g.user_id == None %}
    <h5>Please click the button below to login using your <font color="blue"><b>CSUF credential</b></font>:</h5><p></p>
    <!-- google sign in button -->
    <div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="{{google_client_id}}"
        data-ux_mode="redirect"
        data-login_uri="https://localhost:3000/login"
        >
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="pill"
        data-theme="filled_black"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
         data-width=100
        data-logo_alignment="left">
    <p></p>
{% else %}
    Welcome {{g.user_first}}
    <p></p>
    <p>
        Sign out of Google to log out.
    </p>
    <p></p>
{% endif %}

</div>



First, change https to http on your data-login_url, and as you confirmed from the documentation, make sure both http://localhost and http://localhost:3000 are authorised JavaScript origins.
After you do the above, try to clear your cache and restart your browser.
If you are using Chrome, it sometimes, forcefully, redirects to https. In that case, you may want to try a different browser or use incognito mode.
